# Creating Headers on Separate Lines

Tags: php, html

I have 3 headers and they are displaying on the same line. What can I put in the style so that this does not happen?

```
 <h2><?php echo "Name:  "; echo $rows['a_name']; ?></h2>
 <h2><?php echo "Topic: ";echo $rows['a_email']; ?></h2>
 <h2><?php echo  "Message:"; echo $rows['a_answer']; ?></h2>
```

Comment: Header elements are block level by default, so you must have some CSS that changes that behavior. Post your CSS please. Also, your PHP is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: never heard of a line break? <br />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<h2>` is a `display:block` tag by default.

Make sure you have not overridden such property inside your CSS definitions [e.g. `display-inline`].

Comment: Thanks! It turns out is was overwritten in the external css so I changed it to display:block.

Answer (score 0):

you could insert a [`<br>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) to break the lines, like so:

```
 <h2><?php echo "Name:  "; echo $rows['a_name']; ?></h2><br>
 <h2><?php echo "Topic: ";echo $rows['a_email']; ?></h2><br>
 <h2><?php echo  "Message:"; echo $rows['a_answer']; ?></h2>
```

alternatively, you could set the css property `display` of `h2`to `block` either in a separate `css` file, a `<style>` tag, or in each `h2`'s individual style attribute:

```
 h2 { display: block; }
```

Comment: `<br>` should not be used for design/layout purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a line break.
    `<br />`

You could use paragraph tags (make sure they are properly nested)
    `<p>blaah blaah blaah</p>`

or you could move them around with divs. (Not recommended)

```
<div>Blaah blaah blaah</div>
```

CSS (I assume you know how to use CSS)

```
div {
position:(absolute, relative or fixed)
top:___;
left:____;
}
```